# count one occurrence per person per date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that pulls which insurance a person used and the date of service.  If a person used a medical insurance AND a dental insurance on the same exact date, I want to only count the medical insurance.

```
With medical as
   ( select p.person_nbr as PNum
    , pe.date
    , pm.payer
    , 'Medical' as PayerGroup
    from person p
JOIN patient_encounter pe on p.person_id = pe.person_id
JOIN payer_mstr pm on pe.payer_id = pe.payer_id
where pm.payer like '%Medical%'

--insert medical into and create temp table 
SELECT
PNum
,Date
,Payer
,PayerGroup
INTO #WTEMP
FROM Medical; 

With dental as
   ( select p.person_nbr as PNum
    , pe.date
    , pm.payer
    ,'Dental' as PayerGroup
    from person p
JOIN patient_encounter pe on p.person_id = pe.person_id
JOIN payer_mstr pm on pe.payer_id = pe.payer_id
where pm.payer like '%Dental%'

--insert dental into temp table 
SELECT
PNum
,Date
,Payer
,PayerGroup
INTO #WTEMP
FROM Dental; 

--Pull from temp
select Pnum
,Date
,Payer
,PayerGroup
FROM #WTEMP
DROP TABLE #WTEMP;
```

I basically just want to eliminate dental records if that person had a medical visit that day

Comment: Can you please be explicit about the problem your having. Maybe include sample data, what you WANT to get, vs. what you ARE getting? What you've tried and what hasn't worked?

Comment: The code as presented will fail. The second `INSERT...INTO #WTEMP` will fail because the table already exists. And the two inserts have different schemas, so the data points aren't going to line up. And once it's all in the temp table, how do you distinguish medical from dental? This needs some work. [Start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the GROUP BY clause.

Assuming `Payer` is the "person" and `Date` is the "date of service", you could try:

SELECT Pnum, Date, Payer, PayerGroup FROM #WTEMP
GROUP BY Payer, Date
DROP TABLE #WTEMP;

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windowing Functions such as Row_Number(), Partition the data by PNum and Date and order the data by Payer.

The output will be like this

```
abc, '2019-03-01', 'Medical', 1
abc, '2019-03-01', 'Dental', 2
```

Filter the 1's

Note: I'm not sure whether your SELECT INTO #WTEMP will work for both Medical and Dental.. as the table is already created.